How to configure ansible-pull to work with subdirectories
The command ansible-pull -U https://oauth2:$GITHUB_TOKEN@github.com/user/project.git -d .ansible/pull/project successfully clones the repository to ~/.ansible/pull/project.
But how can I use the working directory infrastructure/src/main/resources/ansible/ inside the repository with the inventory file site.yaml
